# Unity load files from outside of resources folder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In unity is it possible to load a resource that is out side of the resources folder. I want the user to be able to set a textAsset variable from a file outside of the Assets directory entirely.

Comment: What type of resources file?

Comment: Text assets. Why does it matter?

Comment: It matters because there are other resources types like png, txt, jpeg.  `TextAsset`  is Unity specific and the answer depends on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't load `TextAsset` from an external path(path not in the Unity game). In fact, you can't even load it from a path in the project itself which is not the Resources path which is then loaded with the [`Resources`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326248/using-resources-folder-in-unity/41326276#41326276) API.

One option you have is to use the AssetBundle. Add the `TextAsset` to the Assetbundle then you can [load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47030894/build-and-load-assetbundles-in-unity/47033537#47033537) the Assetbundle from any path and extract the `TextAsset` from it.

If you just want to load any file outside the Unity path, you can do this **without** `TextAsset`. Just use any of the `System.IO` API such as `File.ReadAllText` an `File.ReadAllBytes`. This should be able to load your file.