# Load Spritesheet/Atlas through Streaming Assets

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am trying to allow a degree of modding in my Unity game by utilizing streaming assets.  I can import a single sprite no problem, but I am not sure how to set an imported streaming assets sprite to Sprite Mode: Multiple and slice that sprite into its sub parts.

Here is a test class I am using for the import right now:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using PixelsoftGames.Tools2D;
using System.IO;

public class Sandbox : MonoBehaviour
{
    SpriteRenderer sRenderer = null;

    private void Awake()
    {
        sRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Application.streamingAssetsPath);
        FileInfo[] allFiles = directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.*");

        foreach(FileInfo file in allFiles)
            if(file.Name.Contains("Laser"))
                StartCoroutine("LoadSprite", file);
    }

    IEnumerator LoadSprite(FileInfo file)
    {
        if (file.Name.Contains("meta"))
            yield break;
        else
        {
            string fileWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.ToString());

            string finalPath;
            WWW localFile;
            Texture2D texture;

            finalPath = "file://" + file.ToString();
            localFile = new WWW(finalPath);

            Debug.Log(finalPath);

            yield return localFile;

            texture = localFile.texture;
            texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
            Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(texture as Texture2D, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 32f);
            sRenderer.sprite = sprite;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just drop a Sprite sheet in the StreamingAssets folder and expect to access it directly in a build. Since Sprite sheet is in Unity format, you have to use one of Unity's resources/asset API to access it. There are two ways to do this:

**1**.With the [`Resources`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41326276/3785314) API. This means you must use the Resources folder instead of the StreamingAssets folder. Put the Sprite atlas in the Resources folder then read as follow:

```
Sprite[] sprite = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("spriteFile") as Sprite[];
```

**2**.If you want to use the StreamingAssets folder, you must build the Sprite sheet as Assetbundle then use the `AssetBundle` API read it during run-time. The `AssetBundle.LoadAssetWithSubAssets` and `AssetBundle.LoadAssetWithSubAssetsAsync` (Recommended) functions are used to load Sprite atlas.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47033537/3785314) shows how to build AssetBundle. Ignore the loading part because loading sprite atlas is different from loading a normal Texture. Once you build it, see below for how to load it. The sprite atlas is stored in the `loadedSprites` variable:

```
public Image image;

string nameOfAssetBundle = "animals";
string nameOfObjectToLoad = "dog";

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadAsset(nameOfAssetBundle, nameOfObjectToLoad));
}

IEnumerator LoadAsset(string assetBundleName, string objectNameToLoad)
{
    string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "AssetBundles");
    filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(filePath, assetBundleName);

    //Load "animals" AssetBundle
    var assetBundleCreateRequest = AssetBundle.LoadFromFileAsync(filePath);
    yield return assetBundleCreateRequest;

    AssetBundle asseBundle = assetBundleCreateRequest.assetBundle;


    //Load the "dog" Asset (Use Sprite since it's a Sprite. Use GameObject if prefab)
    AssetBundleRequest asset = asseBundle.LoadAssetWithSubAssetsAsync<Sprite>(objectNameToLoad);
    yield return asset;

    //Retrive all the Object atlas and store them in loadedSprites Sprite
    UnityEngine.Object[] loadedAsset = asset.allAssets as UnityEngine.Object[];
    Sprite[] loadedSprites = new Sprite[loadedAsset.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < loadedSprites.Length; i++)
        loadedSprites[i] = (Sprite)loadedAsset[i];

    Debug.Log("Atlas Count: " + loadedSprites.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < loadedSprites.Length; i++)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning(loadedSprites[i].name);

        //Do something with the loaded loadedAsset  object (Load to Image component for example) 
        image.sprite = loadedSprites[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the 1.17.x preview version, you can use the following syntax:

```
myAddressableSpriteSheet.LoadAssetAsync<Sprite[]>();
```

With myAddressableSpriteSheet being an AssetReferenceTexture2D.
This functionality is not documented anywhere yet but was mentioned in the [Unity forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/loading-spritesheet-sprites-with-assetreference.548155/).