# DLL: Library of Images

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, dll

I'm building a crafting system using Unity but I use .Net heavily for a lot of my stuff. Typically I build all my functions in a .Net DLL and import it into my Unity project. I'm thinking about building a Library of images for my crafting system but I'm not sure what would be the best approach for Unity. It needs to be in a Library I can use for multipal games. the images them selves will not change but I may add to it in the future. So I need something that will allow me to easily update the library. I instantly though of using a DLL to store all the images but I wanted to hear other peoples thoughts before I went down this route. My only other option I can think of would be using SQl but that would bog down my network with requests to download images. Whats the best solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Build and load Assetbundles in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47030894/1092820)

Comment: Not sure. I think its certainly a option I was not aware of before and very helpful. I guess the lead to another question. If I used a .Net dll as a library of images, would it still work in Unity for a IOS or Android App?

Comment: Possibly if you use Net Core https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download By using a DLL you are making your life much harder if you want to be platform independant...